# Unable to fix veracode cwe id 918 flaw (SSRF) when using API gateway pattern in a Microservices architecture

Tags: microservices, asp.net-core-webapi, api-gateway, veracode, ssrf

I am using `API Gateway Pattern` in a `Micro services` architecture in which the `Front End Angular app` makes an `HTTP request` to my `API Gateway` project which is simply a `ASP.net Core 3.1 Web API` project. Currently I only have 2 `micro services` and an `API Gateway` and all of them are of type `ASP.net Core 3.1 Web API` project. The `API Gateway` project has all the controllers of my `micro services`. The purpose of the `API Gateway` is just to receive the request from `Front end` and make an `HTTP Request` to the appropriate `Micro service`.

Now in the `AccountController.cs` of my `API Gateway` project, I have the following code

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the detail of an account by its id
/// </summary>
/// <param name="organizationId">Id of the Organization of which the account belongs to</param>
/// <param name="accountId">Id of Account of which information is being requested</param>
/// <returns>Account's Details</returns>
[HttpGet("{organizationId}/{accountId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAccountAsync(Guid organizationId, Guid accountId)
{
    _uri = new Uri(uriString: $"{_configurationService.AccountAPI}GetAccount/{organizationId}/{accountId}");
    using var result = await _client.GetAsync(_uri);
    var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return Ok(content.AsObject<MessageResponse<AccountDetailVM>>());
}
```

After searching about the `SSRF` issue on stackoverflow I found the following recommendation at [Veracode community](https://community.veracode.com/s/question/0D52T00004i1UiSSAU/how-to-fix-cwe-918-veracode-flaw-on-webrequest-getresponce-method).

> Veracode Static Analysis will report a flaw with CWE 918 if it can
>   detect that data from outside of the application (like an HTTP Request
>   from a user, but also a file that may have been uploaded by a user,
>   database data, webservice data, etc) is able to change the nature of a
>   network request.

On [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58490981/4567504) I found the following fix

> For CWE ID 918 it is hard to make Veracode recognize your fix unless you have static URL. You need to validate all your inputs that become parts of your request URL.

That means I had to sanitize my input parameters `OrganizationId` and `AccountId` before appending them to the request URL.

Also another question on the [veracode community](https://community.veracode.com/s/question/0D52T00004s161D/how-to-fix-cwe918-serverside-request-forgery-ssrf-) suggested

> The only thing that Veracode Static Analysis will automatically detect as a remediation for this flaw category is to change the input to be hardcoded

and they proposed a solution for the query string

> The given example appears to take a model identifier and put it in the
>   URL used in an internal request. We would recommend validating the ID
>   per the rules you have for this datatype (typically this should only
>   be alphanumeric and less than 255 characters) and URLencode it before
>   appending it to a URL.

After all those stuff, I have made the following changes to my code

1. Made sure OrganizationId and AccountId Guid are not empty
2. URL Encoded the string

Here is the code after changes

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the detail of an account by its id
/// </summary>
/// <param name="organizationId">Id of the Organization of which the account belongs to</param>
/// <param name="accountId">Id of Account of which information is being requested</param>
/// <returns>Account's Details</returns>
[HttpGet("{organizationId}/{accountId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAccountAsync(Guid organizationId, Guid accountId)
{
    if (organizationId != Guid.Empty && accountId != Guid.Empty)
    {
        string url = HttpUtility.UrlEncode($"{_configurationService.AccountAPI}GetAccount/{organizationId}/{accountId}");
        using var result = await _client.GetAsync(url);
        var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return Ok(content.AsObject<MessageResponse<AccountDetailVM>>());
    }

    return BadRequest();
}
```

Thats All I could do to sanitize my input parameters `OrganizationId` and `AccountId` but after all those changes `veracode` still identifies a `SSRF` flaw on line

> using var result = await _client.GetAsync(url);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a hack to fix this issue, I just appended the query string parameters to the Base Address of httpClient and `veracode` stopped giving me error.

Here is how the solution looks like

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the detail of an account by its id
/// </summary>
/// <param name="organizationId">Id of the Organization of which the account belongs to</param>
/// <param name="accountId">Id of Account of which information is being requested</param>
/// <returns>Account's Details</returns>
[HttpGet("{organizationId}/{accountId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAccountAsync(Guid organizationId, Guid accountId)
{
    if (organizationId != Guid.Empty && accountId != Guid.Empty)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        //Appended the parameters in base address to
        //to fix veracode flaw issue
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri($"{_configurationService.AccountAPI}GetAccount/{organizationId}/{accountId}");

        //passing empty string in GetStringAsync to make sure
        //veracode doesn't treat it like modifying url 
        var content = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("");

        return Ok(content.AsObject<MessageResponse<AccountDetailVM>>());
    }

    return BadRequest();
}
```